# How was Princess Violet able to use Denna's Agiel, and why didn't it hurt her?

Tags: the-sword-of-truth

I'm reading *Wizard's First Rule* by Terry Goodkind.

At one point Denna allows Princess Violet to use her Agiel on Richard. How is it that the princess (a) can use it (b) does not feel the pain that is caused to the user?

Comment: Agiel is a short magical baton used for torture and is capable of causing extreme amounts of pain.

Comment: Not an answer because I don't trust my memory, but I believe that you only feel pain when you use an Agiel if that Agiel had previously been used to torture you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Agiel's magic works like a chain. We know the following details from the books:

1. Denna was tortured by the same Agiel she used, and she experiences pain when she uses it.
2. Violet can use it without pain.
3. Kahlan holding it on her own does not feel pain, but she can feel it when she touches Richard's hand as he holds it.

From Stone of Tears, the second Sword of Truth novel:

"Kahlan reached out and took the Agiel in her fingers, rolling it back and forth. 'Because of this? Because of what Dena did?' Richard nodded, still staring at the fire. Richard, what does this do?'

Richard looked at her at last. He gripped the Agiel in his fist. 'Touch my hand. Don't touch the Agiel, just my hand.'

Kahlan reached out and put her fingers against his fist.

She jerked back with a yelp of pain. She shook her wrist, trying to ease the sting. 'Why didn't it hurt before when I touched it?'

'Because it was never used to train you.'"

The one case that the books don't cover as far as I know is that there's never a case of someone who was never tortured with the Agiel using it on someone who was also never tortured with it. I expect though nothing would happen.

In other words, only a person who has been tortured by it can continue the chain of magic to another person, but once the magic has been chained, the victim will always feel pain while touching it.

Comment: Do you have quotes from the novel? That would be helpful.